# ERROR: relation "products" does not exist Cloud SQL Postgres + Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect GCP SQL with spring data. I have had success connecting to the database. However, I am not sure why hibernate doesn't seem to recognise the existing table.

Here is my Entity class product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private long product_id;
    @Column(name = "product_name")
     private String productName;
    @Column(name = "image_url")
     private String imageURL;
    @Column(name = "close_date")
     private LocalDate closeDate;
    @Column(name = "deliver_date")
     private LocalDate deliverDate;
    @Column(name = "slot")
     private int slot;
    @Column(name = "price")
     private double price;
    @Column(name = "seller_id")
     private long sellerId;

    public Product(String productName, String image, LocalDate closeDate, LocalDate deliverDate, int slot, double price, long sellerId){
        this.productName = productName;
        this.imageURL = image;
        this.closeDate = closeDate;
        this.deliverDate = deliverDate;
        this.slot = slot;
        this.price = price;
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties The sql instance is named warehouse and the database is named warehouse as well while the warehouse is named products.

```
    # JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=//pass

#Logging
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#GCP
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=warehouse
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=//pid:asia-southeast2:warehouse
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=//pid
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=//cred
```

Here is my test controller on which i test the code:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(){
    repo.save(prod);
    return "added";
}
```

I really do not understand what have I been doing wrong here:

```
    2020-08-26 00:10:47.326  INFO 8924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        products
        (close_date, deliver_date, image_url, price, product_name, seller_id, slot) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-08-26 00:10:47.685  WARN 8924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2020-08-26 00:10:47.685 ERROR 8924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "products" does not exist
  Position: 13
2020-08-26 00:10:47.834 ERROR 8924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist
  Position: 13
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:119) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
```

My table do exists

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM products
postgres-> ;
 product_id | product_name | image_url | close_date | deliver_date | slot | price | seller_id 
------------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------+------+-------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

I really feel like hitting a bedrock, I don't understand what is wrong haha

Comment: Could you please provide your table `products` DDL.

Comment: For the following code, where is the prod object coming from? How is it initialized. I'm assuming its global.  @GetMapping("/test")
public String test(){
    repo.save(prod);
    return "added";
}

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the silly problem was i created the table on postgres default database instead of warehouse. I am very sorry for wasting your time. Thank you for reading through!